# XPath: Retrieving text within p tags?

Tags: html, xpath-1.0

I have the following HTML code:

```
        <div id="mrkplc">

                        <p>Sold by 
                            Cameta Camera
                        </p>

                    <p class="title intShipHide">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="sywrSellerPopup intShipHide">ShopYourWay Guarantee Seller</a>
                    </p>

        </div>
```

I want to retrieve the information "Cameta Camera" using XPath but am not sure how to approach this. The current XPath I am using is:

```
"//div[@id='mrkplc']"
```

This will give me a list of all the divisions, but how do I parse through that list to get the text I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring-after` to cut of the "Sold by" string and `normalize-space` to strip the whitespace in between.

```
normalize-space(substring-after(//div[@id='mrkplc']/p[1], 'Sold by'))
```

Some implementations will not remove newlines using `normalize-space`, you might want to use `translate` if so (or remove the whitespace outside of XPath).